# Using Digest Auth and Sending POST data with curl

Tags: php, post, curl, digest, digest-authentication

I have a question regarding HTTP Digest Auth using curl, and sending post data at the same time.

I have a REST API, and each resource in it needs authentication. I access my resources from my website using php curl. Each resource needs to authenticate using digest.

I'm using CURLAUTH_DIGEST for this, and it usually works like a charm.

The problem is when I try to send additional data in POST, using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, that data will not be sent alongside with digest auth information. **Why is this? How can I fix this?**

I'm using PHP 5.4.3 with php curl 7.25.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem to combine Digest authentication with `POST` requests.

Make sure to double check if you are suppose to do:

1. a *basic* `POST` (the equivalent of `-X POST -d 'body-content-here'` with `curl` CLI),
2. or a `multipart POST` (e.g. `-F image_file=@"foo.jpg"` to upload a given file).

Also what I greatly recommend is to interact with your API via `curl` command-line tool and use the `--libcurl request.c`: it will write into this output C file a convenient recap of all the options used to perform the request, and then you will simply have to copy/adapt them on your side.

At last, feel free to refer to this [PHP code sample](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-api/blob/master/moodstocks-api/msapi.php) that illustrates how to perform such calls.

Comment: I have the following structure:

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'test:test';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameterString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

POST data goes empty to the server.

Comment: As suggested could you perform the same request successfully using `curl` in command-line? (if not double check your web service). Is `$parameterString` properly set?

Comment: Checked, when using digest it wont send POST data, when using basic it will send it correctly. I used curl 7.28 for the command line. I also noticed something, it's like it tried to do 2 requests: A first one for the Auth request, and a second one for the data (but fails finding it), but I'm not sure of any of this.

Comment: Everything is normal vs. the 2 requests: see [how Digest authentication works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation). Also I do confirm you should not encounter any error by combining `POST` and `Digest`: the company I work for provides an HTTP API with this exact same configuration. At last I've just performed a check with curl 7.28.0 and it works perfectly. Double check your web service, and you client-code.

Comment: After many testings I've found that indeed cURL doesnt has problems with POSTs and Digest Auth. My problem lies on the htaccess file. For some reason, curl with post and digest auth does not work with vanity url. Any ideas of how would you fix this?

Comment: I suggest you to open a new specific question on that!